# How resize layout when keyboard shown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, resize, chat, android-softkeyboard

Good morning to everybody, I have a little problem about resizing of layout when keyboard is shown.

[image]

[image]

In manifest I have adjustResize and also I tried to use adjustPan but I have problem with scrolling of recyclerview.

My layout code is:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/layoutGeneralHome"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.fragment_home">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listChatGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:hint="Scrivi messaggio"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="INVIA"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks who could help me

Comment: Use scrollView in your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no need to add scrollview, Using Relative layout U can achieve Screen like u want.
I have add Relative layout and Code like below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listChatGeneral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llSendView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSendView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Scrivi messaggio" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="INVIA"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I removed LinearLlayout but it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is my view in my app, it's work fine, Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:mContext="hvasoftware.com.tudiendanhngon.view.activities.CommentActivity">




    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewComment"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:paddingLeft="9dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/ibUpComment" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibUpComment"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edtComment"
            ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edtComment" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarUpload"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edtComment"
            ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/edtComment"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your view example but I'm unable to actualize it to my situation. Can you explain me the logic of layout and why it should works?

Comment: It's can, you do not read enough. My code very simple, scrollview auto resize layout when keyboard visible, that it's.

Comment: Yes but you have only textView and editText (I suppose the results expected are different), I only have recyclerView, editText and Button. I tried insert a scrollView but result is not as I exptected because editText and button are fix to bottom and I have to scroll every time down to see them

Comment: Ok fine, i update my answer, it's work 100%. The key is ConstraintLayout

Comment: Yes, I undestand your logic when find solution with RelativeLayout but also Constraint could be fine. Thank you for your time!

Comment: ConstraintLayout is the best right now, you can do anything with it, simple and powerful